# How do I parse the SMS sender's from number and body of what s/he texted to Twilio number via a webhook and node.js?

Tags: node.js, twilio, webhooks, twilio-twiml

[image]Hello StackOverflow Friends:

The following code works fine, I've tested with nGrok running locally.

Two of the requirements I have left and can't figure out are:

1. Capture the phone number of the sender (put in variable)
2. Capture the body of the text the sender sent (put in variable)

Many thanks in advance!

```
const express = require('express');
const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;
const app = express();


});

app.post('/sms', (req, res) => {

// Start our TwiML response.
 const twiml = new MessagingResponse();


// Add a text message.
const msg = twiml.message('some canned response');



res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
res.end(twiml.toString());
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can get the inbound message from an incoming SMS webhook request with `req.body.Body` and the inbound phone number with `req.body.From`.

To save into a variable, maybe something like `const inbMsg = req.body.Body` and `const inbPhoneNum = req.body.From`.

For more information on [parsing an incoming Twilio SMS Webhook with Node.js, I'd recommend this blog post by my teammate Sam Agnew](https://www.twilio.com/blog/parsing-an-incoming-twilio-sms-webhook-with-node-js).

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: Hi @lizziepika I'll read the link from you with Sam Agnew's blog post tonight. I tried the above and get the following error. I'm also going to have to learn how to set break points in VS Code and Node.js, when I had done this before in C# I could at least step through the code, now it just blows past the breakpoint.

Comment: sourceComponent "14100"
httpResponse "500"
url "https://8.ngrok.io/sms"
ErrorCode "11200"
LogLevel "ERROR"
Msg "Internal Server Error"
EmailNotification "false"

Comment: I tried the link example you mentioned and got the following error. sourceComponent "14100"
httpResponse "500"
url "https://4.ngrok.io/sms"
ErrorCode "11200"
LogLevel "ERROR"
Msg "Internal Server Error"
EmailNotification "false"

Comment: Hi @lizzipika I added   
  const inbPhoneNum = req.body.From and that was added just below the existing const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

Comment: does it run if you comment out that line you added?

Comment: Do you have any body parsing middleware setup? Parameters in Twilio webhooks are form encoded, so you likely need `app.use(express.urlencoded());` so that Express parses the parameters into the `req.body` object.

Comment: @philnash Thanks. No. I spent an hour trying to find out how to include the above in my code and look for a more complete code example on Twilio and no luck yet.

Comment: @philnash and lizziepika: I found this Twilio document (link below) and between both of your's fine help and it I've gotten the syntax and the incoming number. I can't thank you enough!!!!!!!  https://www.twilio.com/blog/parsing-an-incoming-twilio-sms-webhook-with-node-js

Comment: Hooray, glad you got it sorted and sorry I wasn’t more clear in my comment.

Comment: Thank you phil

Comment: @philnash oh you were good, I'm just spooling up to JS - it's me! Thanks again.